# Focusing Form within Private Shared Method

Tags: vb.net, winforms, focus

I have in my appliacyion a Private Shared method which runs an external exe in 'Normal' Focus mode upon clicking. 
After exe completes, a MsgBox Popup showing successfull completeion or failure of process with Default OK Button.

When the user clicks OK Button the MainForm hides or minimize. How can I get Focus of mainform.

I tried using 'Me.Activate()' But it says Me can only valid withing an intance.

What I tried is large code but important parts shown below():

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class MainForm
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Dim WithEvents Calculate As New Button()
    Dim myProcess As Process = Nothing
    ...
    ...

<STAThreadAttribute()> _
 Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim myMainForm As New MainForm
    Application.Run(myMainForm)
  End Sub

Public Sub New()
    ...
End Sub

Private Shared Sub Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click

    Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
        RunArgs = "SomeFile.txt"
        p.Arguments = RunArgs
        p.FileName = "Example.exe"
    myProcess = Process.Start(p)
    myProcess.WaitForExit()

    If(myProcess.ExitCode = -99) Then
        MsgBox("Successfully completed...", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Success")
    Else
        MsgBox("Failed...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Failed")
        Exit Sub    
    End If

End Class
```

Comment: Why does this method need to me `Shared`?

Comment: Because 'Calculate' Button in this form, is enabled/disable by other form. Therefore, It must be shared.

Comment: That form can be use in a Global variable. Then, this method won't need to be shared